# Powershell: get into system directories?

Tags: powershell

i'm writing very usefull script in PS and it's my first script :D And the question is: how to get into system directory ex. C:\Recovery (Windows 7) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
 just add -force and ofcorse run as Admin

Comment: In my systems (windows 7 or  windows server 2008 R2) just need to run as administrator. Never used -force

Answer (score 2):

Run powershell **as administrator** and the

```
Set-location c:\recovery
```

or using the Set-Location alias (***EDIT after comments***)

```
cd c:\recovery
```